# How to return bad request on the controller class layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

on my controller function, i tried to get the token to verify it, however i was trying to stop the function being executed if the token is invalid, this is what i did
[image]

however the result will still continue to execute to function layer and execute the function, may i know how i can stop the code being executed and return them the 401 - Unauthorized?

Comment: Have you considered throwing an exception?

Comment: @lax48 yes, but i tried to return a proper message is much more better than throw exception

Comment: You could add a message to the exception and then show it later when you catch it

Comment: Otherwise I think you need to use an `out` argument to let the caller know what the error is. It is a bit more tricky than the exception

Comment: are you trying to implement jwt auth? if yes it's weird implementation of it. read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0
and this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
return Unauthorized();
```

Or

```
return StatusCode(401);
```

In your controller method that is being accessed (not the controller constructor).

Although you better off using Microsoft Identity to manage authentication and authorization, so you can just decorate your methods with

```
[Authorize]
[Authorize(Roles="")]
```

Comment: You can't actually do in this way AFAIK: the OP's function is a constructor, so it can't return anything

Comment: @lax48 that's why I said that they should put in the method being accessed, not in the constructor.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that. On the other hand, this method should not be called by the constructor, otherwise we are in the same situations. So this solution works only if the OP can change the structure of his class